# Detect which link was clicked? Always returns undefined. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect which of the first 3 links is being clicked on by outputting the links ID.

It always returns `undefined`.

What's wrong?

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {

         onclick = function() {
            alert(this.id);
            return false;
         }
          }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <a class="a" name="a" id="1" href="#">---1---</a>
    <a class="a" name="a" id="2" href="#">---2---</a>
    <a class="a" name="a" id="3" href="#">---3---</a>

    <a href="#"> normal link </a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing in that code attaches event handlers to any elements.

Comment: Oh, also, if you're going to use jQuery anyway, don't do your initializations in an old-fashioned "window.onload" handler like that. Use either a "ready" handler, or set up your "load" handler with jQuery.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not targeting any of the links.

```
  window.onload = function() {
    $("a.a").click(function() {
      alert(this.id);
      return false;
    });
  }
```

What this is doing (`$("a.a").click(function(){`) is looking for any click events on anchors of class name 'a' and run the following anonymous function.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't used even a single bit of Jquery. Check here for the jquery version that i made on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8tu8W/

Answer (score 2):

Modified your HTML a bit

```
<a class="a" name="a" id="anch1" href="#">---1---</a>
    <a class="a" name="a" id="anch2" href="#">---2---</a>
    <a class="a" name="a" id="anch3" href="#">---3---</a>

    <a href="#"> normal link </a>
```

Changed your anchor ids and introduced document ready event.

```
$(function(){
    $("a.a").click(function(){
        alert (this.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. You will add clickable links to array, then bind click event to document, in event method you will get target of click a find if it is and on which position in array.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var clickableLinks = [];
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for(var i=0,len=links.length;i< len;i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    if(link.className.split(" ").indexOf("a") != -1) { // Or another detection
      clickableLinks[clickableLinks.length] = link;
    }
  }
  document.attachEvent('onclick', clicked); // IE
  document.addEventListener('click', clicked, false); // Other browsers

  function clicked(event) {
    var target;
    if (event.target) {target = event.target};
if (event.srcElement) {target = event.srcElement};
    var index = clickableLinks.indexOf(target);  
    if(index != -1) {
      alert("clicked at", index+1, "link");
    }
}
```